# Show all events from today to all previous

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an events listing website with a section that show all previous events.  I need to show all events from today, back.  I am currently showing an archive of all events with the code below, but need to modify it accordingly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  "This is the Archive of all events" here ->  http://www.1111presents.com/2014/events/

```
     <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

            $theTitle = "".__('Archive of All Events', 'eventful_theme')."";

            if (get_query_var('period')) {
            $theDate = preg_split("/-/", get_query_var( 'period' ));

            if (isset($theDate[0]) && isset($theDate[1]) && isset($theDate[2]) ) {
                $theTitle = __('Events on ','eventful_theme').strftime('%e %B %Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, (int) $theDate[1], (int) $theDate[2], (int) $theDate[0]));           
                $period_start = mktime(0, 0, 0, (int) $theDate[1], (int) $theDate[2], (int) $theDate[0]);
                $period_end = mktime(23, 59, 59, (int) $theDate[1], (int) $theDate[2], (int) $theDate[0]);

     } else { ?>
```

And here is the additional query code:

```
    <?php
        }
        }

        if (get_query_var('artist_events')) {
        $wp_query = new WP_Query( 
                array( 
                    'post_type' => 'events', 
                    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'), 
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
                    'meta_key' => 'events_date_start_epoque',
                    'order' => 'ASC', 
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'artists_tag',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => get_query_var('artist_events') ,
                                    ),
                                ),
                ) 
            );
        }

        $wp_query = new WP_Query( 
            array( 
                'post_type' => 'events', 
                'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'), 
                'orderby' => 'date', 
                'meta_key' => 'events_date_start_epoque',
                'order' => 'DESC', 
                'paged' => $paged
            )
        );
?>
```

I have put everything together here.

```
       <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $theTitle = "".__('Archive of All Events', 'eventful_theme')."";

        if (get_query_var('period')) {
        $theDate = getdate();

        if (isset($theDate[0]) && isset($theDate[1]) && isset($theDate[2]) ) {
            $theTitle = __('Events on ','eventful_theme').strftime('%e %B %Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, (int) $theDate[1], (int) $theDate[2], (int) $theDate[0]));           
            $period_start = mktime(0, 0, 0, (int) $theDate[1], (int) $theDate[2], (int) $theDate[0]);
            $period_end = mktime(23, 59, 59, (int) $theDate[1], (int) $theDate[2], (int) $theDate[0]);

        } else { ?>

        <div class="dws_bg_dotted dws_margin_top_medium dws_margin_bottom_big">
            <div class="container_24">
                <div class="dws_bg_custom_text dws_general_padding">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
                    } 
        $wp_query = new WP_Query( 
            array( 
                'post_type' => 'events', 
                'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'), 
                'orderby' => 'date', 
                'meta_key' => 'events_date_start_epoque',
                'order' => 'DESC', 
                'paged' => $paged,
                'date_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'before'    => array(
                                'year'  => $theDate["year"],
                                'month' => $theDate["mon"],
                                'day'   => $theDate["mday"],
            ),
        ),
    )
            )
        );
?>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear on what you are trying to achieve.  Are you asking to not have it paginated?  This would require you to show the WP_Query or $wpdb section of the code to identify and help you.

Comment: Thanks Robert.  I added that additional code.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you get what you are looking for

```
$today = getdate();
$wp_query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_type' => 'events', 
        'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'), 
        'orderby' => 'date',    
        'meta_key' => 'events_date_start_epoque',
        'order' => 'DESC', 
        'paged' => $paged,
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'before'    => array(
                    'year'  => $today["year"],
                    'month' => $today["mon"],
                    'day'   => $today["mday"],
                ),
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Hi Robert.  That did help get me closer, but I can still not get the results to list everything before today's date.  If I remove the 'before', I get a full list of dates.  I added the third line about that has everything in it.  Maybe this can help find where i'm messing up?  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: When you have the date_query in there what do you get as a result?  I noticed you are getting $theDate in a if statement and wondering if you were doing that on purpose.  what if the if statement is not triggered?